# javaFX - resizing window horizontally&vertically at once

Tags: javafx, resize, window

How to set the resizing options of application window to resize always horizontally&vertically?

I mean it doesn't matter which side you pick to resize it will increase/decrease both horizontally&vertically by the same value.

So when normally you would resize top by 20px it will resize top/right side by 20x20px etc. Corner resizing would be on single line (diagonal) only.

I know it is silly explanation but I think it is clear to understand my point of view.

Thanks.